# solve Ax=b for outrigger A matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, data-science, linear-algebra

I implement **Crank-Nicolson 2D finite-difference method**.

I get a matrix A which is banded with 1 band above and below the main diagonal, but also contains 2 additional bands , further apart from the main diagonal, so it is NOT penta-diagonal.

A picture showing the structure is below. My matrix is the RHS one. The LHS is easy, it's the penta-diagonal one.
[image]

I couldn't find up until now a way to solve Ax = b with A being the RHS matrix from the photo in python.
I could barely find a name for it, in these lecture notes https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/2/2.086/F12/MIT2_086F12_notes_unit5.pdf it is called an 'outrigger' matrix (page 403).

At the moment I am using `spsolve` from from `scipy.sparse.linalg`, into which I feed two arguments, namely `sparse.csc_matrix(A)` and `sparse.csc_array(b)`, where `A` and `b` have been defined initially as `A = sparse.dok_matrix((size, size), dtype=np.complex64)` and `b = sparse.dok_array((size, 1), dtype=np.complex64)`, then populated with values by iterating element by element through them.
It is extremely slow and I was wondering maybe someone more experienced knows a way to exploit the structure appearing in `A`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should consider ussing the [Gauss-Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method).

If your system is diagonal dominant it will converge, if it is not you probably can make it so by changing using a higher resolution grid.

Where both `x` and `b` have shape `(N, M)` and `A` has shape `(N, N)`.

Let `L = np.diag(np.diag(A))`, `vL = np.diag(A).reshape(N, 1)` and `U = A - L`.

The `inv(L) * (b - U @ x)` iteration can be written as `(b - U @ x) / vL`, so each iteration will have `O(n)` complexity if you use sparse matrices.

If you want to make it even more efficient you can do the multiplications by sum of rolled diagonal matrices.

`np.roll(np.diag(np.roll(A, k, axis=0)) * x[:,0], -k, axis=0).reshape(N, M)`

You can precompute the rolled diagonals, then your matrix multiplication is performed by 4 (or five if the structure is not symmetric) vector multiplications, and some additional rolling and adding operations.